# Combining numpy arrays inside a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, append

I am using a `for` loop to open 12 files in a directory, each representing a month in the year, with shapes as shown:

```
(31, 180, 140)
(28, 180, 140)
(31, 180, 140)
(30, 180, 140)
(31, 180, 140)
(30, 180, 140)
(31, 180, 140)
(31, 180, 140)
(30, 180, 140)
(31, 180, 140)
(30, 180, 140)
(31, 180, 140)
```

I was trying to use `append` to combine these files into one list, as shown:

```
directory = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\TRMM_3B42RT"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    precip_subsetland2010 = []
    for f in filenames:
        if f.startswith("3B42RT_Daily.2010"):
            log = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r')
            datapath2 = (("C:\\Users\\matth\\Downloads\\TRMM_3B42RT\\") + f)
            f = Dataset(datapath2)

            latbounds = [ -45 , -10 ]
            lonbounds = [ 105, 150 ] 
            lats = f.variables['lat'][:] 
            lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

            # latitude lower and upper index
            latli = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
            latui = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) ) 

            # longitude lower and upper index
            lonli = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
            lonui = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )

            precip_subset = f.variables['precipitation'][ : , lonli:lonui , latli:latui ]
            precip_subsetland2010.append(precip_subset)
            precipsubsetland2010 = np.asarray(precip_subsetland2010)
            print(precipsubsetland2010.shape)
```

However, I get an output as shown:

OUTPUT:

```
(1, 31, 180, 140)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(5,)
(6,)
(7,)
(8,)
(9,)
(10,)
(11,)
(12,)
```

I would ultimately like to add the data to a list, then convert into an array with a shape of `(365, 180, 140)`. How can I achieve this? Is this the correct application of `append`?

Comment: Do you guys need any more info to answer this?

Comment: Does `precip_subset` have the shapes you mentioned? Print its shape out.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: The list of shapes I printed at the beginning are the shapes of `precip_subset` of the 12 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the loop, just append `precip_subset` to your list:

```
precip_subsetland2010.append(precip_subset)
```

Outside the loop, call [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), to vertically stack your data.

```
output = np.vstack(precip_subsetland2010)
```

Printing `output.shape` should give you something like `(X, 180, 140)` (`X` being the sum of all rows of the constituent arrays).